# Creating an array of another class

Tags: java, arrays

I kinda need help. Im trying to create an Hash Table using an array of Elements but I keep getting this error, can someone help me? (This array really needs to be an array of Elements).

This is my Element class

```
public class Element<T>{
  T element;
  boolean state;

  public Element(){
    element=null;
    state=false;
  }


  public Element(T elemento){
    element=elemento;
    state=false;
  }
```

this is my HashTable class

```
public class HashTable<T>{
  int maxSize;
  int size;
  float factorCarga;
  private Element<T>[] hash;

  public HashTable(int x){
    this.maxSize=x;
    this.size=0;
    hash =(Element<T>[]) new Object[x];
    factorCarga=0;
  }
```

This is my Test class

```
public class Test{


  public static void main(String args[]){
  HashTable<Element<Integer>> hash = new HashTable<Element<Integer>>(35);
  }

}
```

when i try to run the program i always get this error:

- java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to[LElement;
  at HashTable.(HashTable.java:11) 
  at Teste.main(Teste.java:5) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)

Comment: ***hash =(Element<T>[]) new Object[x]***  you just cant do it like that

Comment: Element<T>[] hash = new Element<T>[17];
 I still get this error;
Error: generic array creation @belwood

Comment: Better yet, here's a good discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: As a general rule: any time you're casting, ask yourself if you're doing it the right way.  When you've finished asking yourself, ask again.  And then one more time, just to be certain.